# Should I use rails 4.2 add foreign_key or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

By release of rails 4.2 [add_foreign_key](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) method was introduced. As far as I understand it is used as combo of migration with `model:references` and `add_index`.

Let's say I only use PostreSQL. (`add_foreign_key` is limited to MySQL and PostreSQL). Should stop using `migration model:references` with `add_index` and start using `add_foreign_key` only?. If yes/no, why?. What are benefits of new `add_foreign_key` method? Is it worth to swap?

Comment: It's not simply limited to combine `model:reference` and `add_index`. It's about adding foreign key constraint to the database. There were no such option before without raw sql or additional gems (such foreiner).

Comment: but the effect (i.e connecting 2 models in relation) is the same, right? (I have little knowledge about databases). How does foreign key constraint vary from integer column with id and index on it?

Comment: You may or may not use `add_foreign_key` method. But, you should either use `model:reference` or `model_id:integer:index` parameters when generating migration. Without this you will not be able to connect two models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foreign key constraints can help with referential integrity (you can't insert data belonging to a book that doesn't exist for example). Foreign keys also provide database level referential integrity as opposed to application level (model validation) integrity.

The Rails team felt it important enough that they now automatically create foreign keys whenever you use references in generating your migrations.

Comment: To my knowledge, Rails doesn't create a foreign key constraint by default. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference